# User Validation Errors in XML File Uploading: Python/Django

Tags: django, authentication, post, file-upload, xml-parsing

When trying to create functionality in a full stack Django/React project that allows a user to upload (specifically XML) files, I ran into an issue in my User validation where it's throwing errors that the userId is not being grabbed. Any feedback is appreciated as this is my first go in XML parsing.

Here are the following relevant files:

```
[
  {
    "model": "easapi.user",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "uid": "123456",
      "name": "Hayley",
      "email": "anemail@g.com"
    }
  }
]


[
  {
    "model": "easapi.log",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "user": 1,
      "dateStart": "2022-11-22",
      "dateEnd": "2022-11-22",
      "dateGenerated": "2022-11-22"
    }
  }
```

```
class User(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Log(models.Model):
  
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  dateStart = models.DateTimeField(max_length=20)
  dateEnd = models.DateTimeField(max_length=20)
  dateGenerated = models.DateTimeField(max_length=20)
  log_hash = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

```
class LogView(ViewSet):
  
  def retrieve(self, request, pk):
    
    log = Log.objects.get(pk=pk)
    serializer = LogSerializer(log)
    return Response(serializer.data)
  
  def list(self, request):
    
    logs = Log.objects.all()
    
    uid_query = request.query_params.get('uid', None)
    if uid_query is not None:
      logs = logs.filter(user=uid_query)
    serializer = LogSerializer(logs, many = True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
  
  @staticmethod
  def generate_unique_log_hash(user_uid):
    while True:
            # Combine user UID, current timestamp, and random seed
            unique_string = f"{user_uid}_{int(time.time())}"
            
            # Generate a hash using SHA-256
            hash_object = hashlib.sha256(unique_string.encode())
            unique_hash = hash_object.hexdigest()
            
            try:
                # Attempt to retrieve a log with this hash
                Log.objects.get(log_hash=unique_hash)
            except Log.DoesNotExist:
                # If the log doesn't exist, this hash is unique
                return unique_hash
  
  def create(self, request):
        user = User.objects.get(uid=request.data['user'])
        # print("User UID:", user_uid)

        
        log_hash = self.generate_unique_log_hash(user.uid)
        print(log_hash)
        log = Log.objects.create(
            dateStart=request.data['dateStart'],
            dateEnd=request.data['dateEnd'],
            dateGenerated=request.data['dateGenerated'],
            user=user,
            log_hash=log_hash
        )
        
        serializer = LogSerializer(log)
        return Response(serializer.data)
  
class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
  class Meta:
    model = Log
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'dateStart', 'dateEnd', 'dateGenerated')
    depth = 1
```

Initially I tried logging the User object to see what it was returning, and at the time that I started refactoring my code , I was getting an object with undefined values.

Now, I am getting variations of the same error that tell me my userId (uid) can't be accessed.

```
File "/views/log.py", line 49, in create
    user = User.objects.get(uid=request.data['user'])
  File "/share/virtualenvs/eas_server-8WC6yVew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
easapi.models.user.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
[14/Aug/2023 20:19:32] "POST /log/ HTTP/1.1" 500 98488`


  File "/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: easapi_log.user_id
```

Here are other options that I tried to implement for the create method which received similar responses:

```
   def create(self, request):
    
     user = User.objects.get(uid=request.data['user'])
     # user = User.objects.get(uid=request.data["user_id"])
     print(user.__dict__)
    
     log = Log.objects.create(
       dateStart = request.data['dateStart'],
       dateEnd = request.data['dateEnd'],
       dateGenerated = request.data['dateGenerated'],
       # user = user
       user = user.uid
     )
   while True:
      try:
        log = Log.objects.create(
            dateStart=request.data['dateStart'],
            dateEnd=request.data['dateEnd'],
            dateGenerated=request.data['dateGenerated'],
             user = user
             # user=user.uid,
        )
         break  # Break the loop if creation is successful
       except IntegrityError:
        # Handle the uniqueness constraint error, e.g., generate a new log_hash
         pass
     serializer = LogSerializer(log)
     return Response(serializer.data)



 def create(self, request):
     try:
         user = User.objects.get(uid=request.data["user"])
     except User.DoesNotExist:
         return Response({"error": "User not found"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
     log = Log.objects.create(
         dateStart=request.data['dateStart'],
         dateEnd=request.data['dateEnd'],
         dateGenerated=request.data['dateGenerated'],
         user=user
     )
     serializer = LogSerializer(log)
     return Response(serializer.data)
```